# Check if object with ManyToMany field already exists for each object from a list

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two models: Pattern and Category.

```
class Pattern(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=u'')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='patterns')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.name)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=u'')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.name)
```

I need to check if each pattern from `valid` already exists or not and properly modify its manytomany `<some_pattern>.categories` field.

Now I'm doing it as follows (`valid` is a list of patterns, `categories` is a queryset of some categories):

```
for pattern in valid:
    obj, created = Pattern.objects.get_or_create(name=pattern)
    if created:
        obj.categories = categories
    else:
        obj.categories.add(*categories)
```

How can I do the same using as few sql queries as possible?

Comment: is your `name` is unique across Pattern table?

Comment: the key to solution was to use bulk_create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution looks as follows:

```
# finding out patterns that not exist in database and creating them
exist = Pattern.objects.filter(name__in=valid)
Pattern.objects.bulk_create([Pattern(name=p) for p in valid if p not in [unicode(pat) for pat in exist]])

# creating new relations
patterns_to_set_category = Pattern.objects.filter(name__in=valid)
relations_to_create = list()
for category in categories:
    for pattern in patterns_to_set_category:
        relations_to_create.append(Pattern.categories.through(pattern=pattern, category=category))
Pattern.categories.through.objects.bulk_create(relations_to_create)
```

Comment: well, this is not exactly equivalent code because in this case you will not create new (missed) `Pattern`s and only get the existing ones. You should also use `bulk_create` for `Pattern` object I guess.